# How to print an initial value using document write

Tags: javascript

My code calculates correctly except I can not get the initial temperature to display, in this case "45.9", to print.

Current output:

function FtoC(Fahrenheit) { return (Fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / 9; } F = 7.722222222222222 C

Where FtoC(Fahrenheit) { return (Fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / 9; } is to equal the number 45.9.

Desired output:

45.9 F = 7.722222222222222 C

Code:

```
<script>
function FtoC(Fahrenheit)
{
return (Fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / 9;
}

var theFahrenheit = FtoC(45.9);
document.write("<br>");
document.write(FtoC + " F = " + theFahrenheit + " C");
</script>
```

Comment: If this is an HTML page then you want to add the content to specific "place" in the page which mean append the new content to an existing element. There are multiple ways for this, for example you can use `let x = document.createElement("span");` in order to create a new <span> element where you can add your new content `x.innerHTML = <add the content which you calculated here>;` and then you append the element to existing element like a div with id="s", using `document.getElementById("s").appendChild(x);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try returning an array from your function FtoC like below:

```
function FtoC(Fahrenheit)
{
return [Fahrenheit, (Fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / 9];
}

var theFahrenheit = FtoC(45.9);

document.write("<br>");

document.write(theFahrenheit[0] + " F = " + theFahrenheit[1] + " C");
```

or Else if you already know the input, you can directly use it instead of returning it in an array.

```
document.write(45.9 + " F = " + theFahrenheit[1] + " C");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>
  function FtoC(Fahrenheit) {
    return (Fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / 9;
  }

  let temperature = 45.9;
  var theFahrenheit = FtoC(temperature);
  document.write("<br>");
  document.write(temperature + " F = " + theFahrenheit + " C");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

On this line:

```
document.write(FtoC + " F = " + theFahrenheit + " C");
```

You're writing out `FtoC`, which is your function, not the temperature. Try introducing a new variable to hold the initial temperature, and write that out to the document instead.

```
<script>
    function FtoC(Fahrenheit)
    {
        return (Fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / 9;
    }

    var theTemp = 45.9
    var theFahrenheit = FtoC(theTemp);
    document.write("<br>");
    document.write(theTemp + " F = " + theFahrenheit + " C");
</script>
```

I also noticed in that line that you're writing `theFahrenheit + " C"` which seems backwards. Since the variable `theFahrenheit` is holding the temperature after conversion, it should be named something else.